# Rails controller: Calling associated model records to index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller, activerecord, controller

I am having an issue with this controller Active record query. I have a model called Submissions and each Submission has an AgentActivity associated with it. I am trying to simply show all Submission fields on a row as well as associated Agent Activity next to it using a db query but I am getting errors with this, is that too simple?:

```
@agent_activities = @submissions.find(:agent_activity)
```

Submission index action

```
def index
 @agent_activities = @submissions.find(:agent_activity)
 @submissions = 
 SubmissionLocation.includes(:submission).where(location_id: 
 current_agent.Company_Business_Location).map(&:submission)
end

     <% @submissions.each do |submission| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= submission.First_Name %></td>
    <td><%= submission.Last_Name %></td>

    <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <td><%= submission.Phone %></td>
    <td><%= submission.Email %></td>
    <%else%>
      <% end %>
    <td><%= submission.Desired_Location %></td>
    <td><%= submission.number_of_beds %></td>
    <td><%= submission.number_of_occupants %></td>
    <td><%= submission.Rent_price_per_month_gbp %></td>


    <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <td><%= submission.Max_move_in_date %></td>
    <td><%= submission.Tenant_Occupation %></td>
    <td><%= submission.Contact_me_on %></td>
    <td><%= submission.Furnished %></td>
    <td><%= submission.Current_Address %></td>
    <td><%= submission.Property_Requirements %></td>

    <%else%>
      <% end %>

      <% Array(@agent_activities).each do |agent_activity|%>

    <td><%= agent_activity.Status %></td>
    <td><%= agent_activity.Notes %></td>

     <% end%>
   <td><%= link_to 'See More', submission %></td>
     <% end %>
```

Submissions model

```
   class Submission < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user, :optional => true


   has_many :agent_activities, inverse_of: :submission
   has_many :agents, through: :agent_activities

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :agent_activities, :reject_if=> proc 
  {|attributes| attributes[:entry].blank?}, :allow_destroy => true

  has_many :submission_locations

  attr_accessor :location_1, :location_2, :location_3
  end
```

Agent Activity model

```
   class AgentActivity < ApplicationRecord

   belongs_to :submission, :optional => true, inverse_of: 
   :agent_activities #has submission_id foreign key in table
   belongs_to :agent, :optional => true, inverse_of: :agent_activities 

   end
```

Comment: Can you please post the actual errors?

Comment: Try @submissions.agent_activities.find...

Comment: Try `Submission.joins(:agents).select('agent_activities.*').load`

Comment: @Deekor im getting a no method error for find

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `@submissions` AFTER you are trying to call `find` on it. You need to reverse the order.

EDIT: Also you are using the association wrong. It doesnt look like you have a `SubmissionLocation` model.

Should be:

```
def index
 @submissions = Submission.where() #fill this query out
end
```

And then when looping through `submissions` on the view you can call `submission.agent_activities`

Comment: Hi, I don't think this is very clear. When you say fill query out, what do you mean by that? I am looking for the query that you would use to reveal the data. e.g Submission.includes(:agent_activities).where(agent_id: current_agent.id).map(&:agent_activity)?

Comment: do you only want to see agent activities of your current user? @WernerAdewole im having a hard time getting the context of what a submission and agent activity is. your post says singular agent activity per submission but your code says many agent activities per submission